# Call jAlerts from Google

Tags: jquery

I will change all the alerts in a Website with jalert of jQuery. I have been programming that. In this Website I called jQuery.min from Google and "migrate" from jquery.com, but I couldn't call jquery.alerts.js from Google, so I have to call it only from one of my servers but I don't want to do it. Knows somebody knows the correct link?? What do you think is wrong in my code?? bellow you can find the call's code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- llava de la página de jquery a...pues a jquery jeje -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script> <!-- migra para que las funciones viejas funcionen -->

<script type="text/javascript">window.jquery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.alerts.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//sites.google.com/site/cssjavascrip/jquery/jquery.alerts.js"></script>





<link href="/path/to/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alertas</title>
</head>
```

Comment: You *couldn't* call it? Why not? Was there an error? Are you using a debugging tool?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, with this line: <script type="text/javascript">window.jquery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.alerts.js"><\/script>')</script>...it work. Because jquery.alerts.js is in my server. But without that, if I only call the file in Google's servers, then the alert don't work, so for that I need help. I have a wrong link but I dont find another one. In this link there is the file but not for this case.
And yes, if I only call the file in Google so the alert never happen.

Comment: Oh!! and with a console I can read that: Refused to execute script from 'http://sites.google.com/site/cssjavascrip/jquery/jquery.alerts.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. Untitled-1.html:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jAlert is not defined

Comment: Yeah, google does that because it doesn't want you using it's CDN for that javascript file.

Comment: Oh, thats bad. Well, thanks, my friend!!